# Passing $routeParams from angularjs to spring controller

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

This is what I have in my AngularJs controller

```
.when("/MutualFriends:topicId", {templateUrl: "MutualFriends", controller: "conMFriends"})

app.controller('conMFriends',function($scope,$routeParams){
$scope.otherId = $routeParams.topicId;
});
```

This is my Spring Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/controlerM", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
public ModelAndView controlerM(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
ModelAndView model = null;
session=request.getSession(true);
user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");

List<ends1> ends=(List<ends1>) ifriendlistservice.getends(user.getId(),5);
    session.setAttribute("MutualFriends", MutualFriends);
model = new ModelAndView("ends");

return model;
```

I am able to fetch the topicId from my AngularJS page in AngularJS controller (with $scope.otherId), however I am unable to pass this value to my Spring controller, from where I am redirecting to new page.

Please help.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates, http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestparam